# I lost my village and forgot the password

Tags: clash-of-clans

I lost my saved village, but forgot the password.

Is there any chance I can still get back my account?

Comment: You should ask Clash of Clans support.

Answer (score 2):

This information is from [Supercell Support for Clash of Clans](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web):

For [Apple devices](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=hot-topics&f=i-can-t-remember-my-game-center-account-and-password):

> If you've lost access to your Game Center or Apple ID, [please ask Apple for assistance](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/).

Once you regain access, try this:

> 1. Log into Game Center using the e-mail address that you originally connected to your account. To do this, go to your device settings > Game Center > Apple ID.
> 2. Once you’re logged into the correct Game Center/Apple ID, the game will prompt a message asking you to load the correct village. If you can’t retrieve your lost village with the address you’re using now, it's probably not the right one.

<sub>[(Source)](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=lost-village&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&l=en)</sub>

---

For Android:

> If you cannot access your Google account, please follow the troubleshooting in this [Google help center article](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2943007?hl=en#ts=2402552).
>
> If you have forgotten your password or Google account credentials please use this [account recovery form](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/?rd=1).

Once you regain access, try this:

> 1. Make sure you have added the correct Google Play account to your device.
> 2. In the in-game settings, tap on the Google Play button (this button should appear in red). This should prompt a screen that will ask you to load the correct village -the village (Town Hall) level 1 and your old village you lost. Confirm the data that appears there (name of the village, level, and last time played) and select your main village.

<sub>[(Source)](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=lost-village&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&l=en)</sub>